# How to change quantity and remove items for a shopping cart application

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a shopping cart application which I can currently add products to and remove them visibly but it does not update the total cost. I need to add this functionality and be able to update the quantity with some buttons which are in the display cart function. I tried using an onClick function but cant figure it out. Below is my JavaScript and a link to my application please let me know if you need any more information.

https://connorlewis128.github.io/ShoppingPage/Dist/product.html

In the cart there are three buttons an x which removes the products and two arrows for increaing and decreasing quantity.
remove buton

```
<i  class="btn-remove fas fa-times-circle"></i>
```

increase

```
<span> <i  class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left btn-minus" ></i> </span>
```

decrease

```
<span> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right btn-plus"></i></span>
```

JS

```
let carts = document.querySelectorAll('#add-to-cart');
let favorites = document.querySelectorAll('#favorite');
console.log(favorites)
let products = [
  {
    name:'ZIPPERED HOODED SWEATSHIRT',
    Tag:'https://connorlewis128.github.io/ShoppingPage/Dist/images/new%20product/black%20jacket/front.webp',
    price:50.00,
    inCart:0
  }
]


// add to cart
for (let i =0; i < carts.length; i++) {
  carts[i].addEventListener('click', () =>{
    cartNumbers(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i])
  })
}

function onLoadCartNumbers(){
  let productNumbers =localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');

  if(productNumbers){
    document.querySelector('span .navbarCart').textContent = productNumbers;
  }
}

// Number of items added to cart
function cartNumbers(products) {
  let productNumbers = localStorage.getItem('cartNumbers');
  productNumbers = parseInt(productNumbers);
  if(productNumbers){
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers', productNumbers + 1) ;
    document.querySelector('span .navbarCart').textContent = productNumbers + 1;

  }  else{
    localStorage.setItem('cartNumbers',1) ;
    document.querySelector('span .navbarCart').textContent = 1;
  }

  
  setItems(products);
}
// favorites
for (let i =0; i < favorites.length; i++) {
  favorites[i].addEventListener('click', () =>{
    favItems(products[i]);
    totalCost(products[i])
  })
}


function onLoadfavNumbers(){
  let favNumbers = localStorage.getItem('favItems');

  if(favNumbers){
    document.querySelector('span .favoritesCount').textContent = favNumbers;
  }
}




// number of favorites added
function favItems(products) {
  let favNumbers = localStorage.getItem('favItems');
  favNumbers = parseInt(favNumbers);
  if(favNumbers){
    localStorage.setItem('favItems', favNumbers + 1) ;
    console.log(favNumbers)
    document.querySelector('span .favoritesCount').textContent = favNumbers + 1;

  }  else{
    localStorage.setItem('favItems',1) ;
    document.querySelector('span .favoritesCount').textContent = 1;
  }
  
  
  setItems(products);
}

  function setItems(products){
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart')
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems)

    if(cartItems != null){
      if(cartItems[products.Tag] == undefined){
        cartItems = {
          ...cartItems,
          [products.Tag]:products
        }
      }
      cartItems[products.Tag].inCart +=1;
    } 
    else{
      products.inCart = 1;
       cartItems = {
          [products.Tag]:products

        }
    }
    localStorage.setItem('productsInCart',JSON.stringify(cartItems));
  }
  function totalCost(products)
  {
    let cartCost =localStorage.getItem('totalCost');
    if (cartCost != null){
      cartCost = parseFloat(cartCost);
      localStorage.setItem('totalCost', cartCost + products.price);
    }
    else{
      localStorage.setItem('totalCost',products.price );
    }

  }

  // display cart
  function displayCart(){
    let cartItems = localStorage.getItem('productsInCart');
    cartItems = JSON.parse(cartItems);
    console.log(cartItems);
    let cartContainer = document.querySelector
    (".products");
    let cartCost =localStorage.getItem('totalCost');

    if(cartItems && cartContainer){
      cartContainer.innerHTML = '';
      Object.values(cartItems).map(products => {
        cartContainer.innerHTML += `
        
        <div class="products">
          
        <span>${products.name}</span>
        <img src="${products.Tag}">
        
        <i  class="btn-remove fas fa-times-circle"></i>

        <div class="productPrice"> $${products.price}</div> 
        <div class="productQuantity"> <span> <i  class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left btn-minus" ></i> </span> <span> ${products.inCart}</span><span> <i class="fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right btn-plus"></i></span></div> 
        <div class="Total"> $${products.price * products.inCart}</div></div>
        `
      });

      cartContainer.innerHTML += `
      <section class="basketTotalContainer">
      <h4 class="basketTotalTitle">
          Basket Total:
      </h4>
      <h4 class="BasketTotal">
          $${cartCost}.00
      </h4>
      </section>`

    }
  };



function removeItem(){
  let removeItem = document.getElementsByClassName('btn-remove');
  console.log(removeItem)
  for (let i = 0; i < removeItem.length; i++){
        let button = removeItem[i]
  button.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    console.log('clicked')
  let removeItem = event.target
  removeItem.parentElement.remove();

});
}}


  





// color change

function colorChange() {
  showcase.style.animation = document.querySelector('input[name="colorradio"]:checked').value + ' 6s infinite';
}

// quantity change
function quantityChange() {
  
  if(document.querySelector('btn-plus'))
  {
    products.inCart = products.inCart +1;
  }
  else if (document.querySelector('btn-minus')){
  products.inCart = products.inCart - 1;}
  }




onLoadCartNumbers();
onLoadfavNumbers();
displayCart();
removeItem();
quantityChange();
```

thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: add only minimal and relevant code, not your entire application..

Comment: @OmriAttiya I edited the code to  only include the cart and product related JS. let me know if something is unclear that I can clarify for you. The application works by adding to something  to the cart on the product page. then if you click on the cart in the top right it will take you to the cart page this is where my problem is

Comment: I don't know if you notice but you have an error at `quantityChange` function. Which means that in the code sequence of:
```
onLoadCartNumbers();
onLoadfavNumbers();
displayCart();
quantityChange();
removeItem();
colorChange();
```
You don't even reach the `removeItem` function so the event listener on the `X` is not happening at all. Debug your code, and you will be fine :D

Comment: I know there is a problem at quantity change but i have updated my code so the remove function now works properly again but i still can not figure out how to change the quantity and update the cart total